# Setting a basic entity while creating a new user in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Im using Devise to create my users in an App with Ruby on Rails.

I have a User model that has a Plan (hobby,premium, etc...)

When creating a new user, I want to add the basic plan to this new user (for business rules needs, I cant leave it blank).

The question is, how can I add this plan when creating this new user?

Here is my controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  clear_respond_to
  respond_to :json

  def save_user_type
    session[:user_type] = params[:user_type]
  end

  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :type, :provider )
  end

end
```

In which method should I add something like this?

```
@user.plan = Plan.first
@user.save
```

Comment: You should use callbacks in model after user create.

Comment: after_create???

Comment: `When creating a new user, I want to add the basic plan` which means without user creation plan or other action can't be performed for said user so it should be after create.

Comment: Must I do a user.save too? 

  after_create do |user|
    user.plan = Plan.first
    user.save
  end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base        
  has_one :plan

  after_create :build_default_plan

  private
  def build_default_plan
    plan.create(#paln_params)
    #.. so on
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Added this line to the user model

```
after_create do |user|
  user.plan = Plan.first
  user.save
end
```

Comment: I have given a sample example in above answer please have a look at that. you can use a block of code in after_create